# Rhyme with Time

Tags: knowledge, rhyme, no-computers

Commonly used units of Time are:

$Second$

$Minute$

$Hour$

$Day$

$Week$

$Month$

$Year$

$Decade$

$Century$

$Millenium$

Can you find at least one rhyming word in English Language for each of them?

Comment: no 'millenium'?

Comment: We can add..just stopped there..I will edit...thx

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a puzzle. It's something to *do*, not something to *solve*.

Comment: Experimenting..feedback well taken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second:

> Reckoned, beckoned

Minute:

> Linnet

Hour:

> Sour\Dour

Day:

> Hay

Week:

> Seek

Month:

> 

Year:

> Her

Decade:

> 

Century:

> Entry

Millenium:

> 

Comment: Her works in British — in North American speak it rhymes better with ‘fear’! Great answers!!

Comment: what about "stunt" for month?

Comment: Rot13 (Praghel - Qbphzragnel, Zvyyravhz - Dhvadhraavhz) (for your missing ones).

Comment: Answers are close enough...like hexomino pointed out, month doesn’t rhyme with any known English word.

Comment: Rot 13 zvyyvbagu rhymes closely enough with month.